# How can I change the background color of my textbox for just a second in Java?

Tags: java, colors, background, sleep

I want to change the color of my textbox to yellow for just a second, but I cant figure out how to. This is my code right now, what it is doing is that it just waits a second and give the textbox the second color.

```
 for(int i=0;i<2;i++){   
   if(i==0)
   {
textbox1.setBackground(Color.yellow); //Turn textbox yellow (first color)

try {
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1); //wait 1 second
} 
catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}       
else if(i==1)
   {
   textbox1.setBackground(Color.white); //Turn textbox white (second color)
   }       
}
```

Ps. I've also tried Thread.sleep(1000); insted of TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your current code, you're putting your entire GUI to sleep, meaning it is frozen and will not show color changes or interact with the user. You should **never** call `Thread.sleep(...)` or similar code on the Swing event thread for this very reason.

Use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead since this was built just for this type of purpose, to provide for time delayed Swing code, either once, or repeatedly.

e.g.,

```
textbox1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
int delayTime = 3 * 1000; // 3 seconds
new Timer(delayTime, new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     textbox1.setBackground(Color.white);
     // stop the timer
     ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
  }
}).start();
```